# Filling empty df with certain amount of values - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

everyone! I'm trying to do something for my wife but am having some issues. I want to create a certain value and replace info column by column.

Here's what I did:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

datalist = ['Sex', 'Race', 'Age', 'FT']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1,size=(3101, 4)), columns=datalist) #I want four columns and 3100 rows.

df = df.replace(to_replace ="0", value ="Female", limit=1752, inplace=True) #I'm trying to turn 1752 of the rows under Sex to be Female, and the rest Male.
```

Before I could get to the male side, I tested the df and found this:

```
    Sex  Race  Age  FT
0  None     0    0   0
1  None     0    0   0
2  None     0    0   0
3  None     0    0   0
4  None     0    0   0
```

Why is Sex returning as none? I've turned off the inplace but it just keeps everything as 0. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You should use _either_ `inplace=True` or assign back.

Comment: `df.replace(to_replace=0, value="Female", limit=1752, inplace=True)` _or_ `df = df.replace(to_replace=0, value ="Female", limit=1752)`

Comment: Your sample code doesn't reproduce the output, but I suspect you assigned to `df["Sex"] = df.replace(...,inplace=True)`? (_inplace_ operations almost always returns `None`). The everything 0 problem is that because your `to_replace` is **str** not `int`. Try `df.replace(to_replace=0, ...)`.

Comment: I'm confused though as to what the goal is because [`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) will replace everywhere in the DataFrame.

Comment: In addition, `limit` in `replace` is not the limit to the number of replacement; it is limit to na filling. What you _should_ be doing is something like `df.loc[:1752, "Sex"] = "Female"`

Answer (score 1):

i think loc method would be efficient to replace value(s) in a column...
actually i don't know the reason why you triy to use replace method tough..

```
df.loc[0:1752-1,'Sex']='Female'
df.loc[df.Sex!='Female',:'Sex']='Male'
print(df)
df.value_counts()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you on your way, if I understand your question(s):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

datalist = ['Sex', 'Race', 'Age', 'FT']
numpy_data = np.random.choice([0,1],size=(3101, 4))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=numpy_data, columns=datalist)
df['Sex'] = df['Sex'].astype(str)
df['Sex'].replace(to_replace ="0", value ="Female", limit=1752, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
df['Sex'] = ['female']*1752 + ['male']*(3101-1752)
```

At the end, you can shuffle your dataframe:

```
df.sample(frac=1)
```